# Python - как подключить модуль?

Tags: python, исключения, pil

День добрый! В консоли получил такой Exception:

```
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

Вопрос: как его подключить.

P.S. Просьба не ругать за глупые вопросы, язык только начал изучать. (Сам я PHP-шник)

**UPD:**

Сорри, забыл код приложить :))

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pip install PIL
```

Для установки этого пакета.

Comment: Спасибо. Еле как поставил :-) 
Под Виндой оказывается лучше из бинарников устанавливать..

Comment: лучше ставить pillow, pil - старый.

Comment: И вам спасибо!